# What are angels created from?

Tags: malaikah

I'm quite curious about the Angels. 
We human being are made up of clay. 
The Shaytan (espiritual) is made up of fire. 
and what the Angels are made up? 
That's the question, JazakAllahkhair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angels are made of *Nur* (light).

> ## خلقت *الملايكة من نور* وخلق الجان من مارج من نار وخلق ادم مما وصف لكم
>
> **The Angels were born out of light** and the Jinns were born out of the
>   spark of fire and Adam was born as he has been defined (in the Qur'an)
>   for you.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/55/78)</sup>

Comment: You may also want to read this article that explains how the Quran beautifully defines the Speed of Light, using the angels, who are made from light. http://www.speed-light.info/miracles_of_quran/speed_of_light.htm